# How can I pass props from one component to another using Link and router in react

Tags: reactjs

```
            <Link to={{
                          pathname: '/Client',
                          state: {
                            bvalue:"Book now"
                          }
                        }}>

                   <button 

                   onChange={(event) =>{
                    event.preventDefault();
                    this.setState={
                      bvalue:"Unavailable",
                      disable:true
                    }
                   }}
                   disabled={this.state.disable}

                  >book now</button></Link>
```

this code is in LandingPage Component

```
const { bvalue} = this.props.location.state
```

above code is in render function of Client Component

now it showing error

> this.props.location is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it something like this. Use state prop and pass necessary items. In the below example visibleFlag which is a boolean is passed along the Link.

```
 <Link to={{
       pathname: '/Client',
       state: {
                visibleFlag: true
        }
  }}>
                   <button
                     onChange={(event) =>{
                       event.preventDefault();
                       this.setState({
                           bvalue:"Unavailable",
                           disable:true
                       })
                     disabled={this.state.disable}
                   >book now</button>
</Link>
```

Accessing:

```
const { visibleFlag } = this.props.location.state
```

Using withRouter HOC to access the router props

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
....
//code 
....
export default withRouter(yourcomponent)
```

Comment: const { visibleFlag } = this.props.location.state, I added this code in render function in Client Component and error is visibleFlag is undefined

Comment: its just for the demo purposes. add the one's you require

Comment: use the withRouter HOC when a component is not being rendered by your router. check the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can pass state/props to other components using Link

```js
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/client',
  state: {
    flag: true
  }
}}>Client</Link>
```

And in target component that will render

```
const { flag } = this.props.location.state;
```

If functional component

```
const { flag } = props.location.state
```

Comment: <Link to={{

                       pathname:'/Client',
                       state:{
                         dvalue:"hired"
                       }
                     }}>                                                                        tried this but showing props.location.state undefined in component Client

Comment: @RihabKasim Kindly updated your code to show your changes